# With this code I get this error "onAddToCart is not a function" How can I fix it?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import { CardMedia, Card, CardContent, CardActions, Typography, IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import { AddShoppingCart } from "@mui/icons-material";
import useStyles from "./styles"




const Product =  ({ product, onAddToCart }) =>{

    const classes = useStyles(); 

    return(
        <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={product.image.url} title={product.name}/>
            <CardContent>
                <div className={classes.cardContent}>
                    <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom >
                        {product.name}                         
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h5"  >
                        {product.price.formatted_with_symbol}                         
                    </Typography>
                    
                </div>
                <Typography dangerouslySetInnerHTML= {{ __html: product.description }} variant="body2"  color="textSecondary"/>
                        
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.cardActions}> 
                <IconButton aria-label="Add to card"  onClick={() => onAddToCart(product.id, 1)}>
                    <AddShoppingCart />
                </IconButton>

            </CardActions>

        </Card>
    )

}

export default Product;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at how the prop onAddToCart is transferred to the component Product

Search something like: `<Product ... />`

Comment: <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                        <Product product={product} onAddToCart={onAddToCart}</Grid>

Comment: here is the code which I have in my products.jsx

Comment: what is 'onAddToCart'
`onAddToCart={onAddToCart}`

Comment: Сan you show code of `onAddToCart`?

Comment: const Products = ( {products, onAddToCart}) => {
    const classes = useStyle();
    return (
        <main className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar}/>
            <Grid>{
                products.map((product) => (
                    <Grid>
                        <Product product={product} onAddToCart={onAddToCart}/>
                    </Grid>
                ))}

            </Grid>
        </main>
    )
}
export default Products;

Comment: Are you sure ‘Products’ component received ‘onAddToCard’ prop?

Comment: Search something like: <Products ... />